# Do you need to recompile PHP to use APC?

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

I have a custom PHP installation which I compiled because the packaged version was too old for my project.

I would need to install APC, do I need to recompile PHP to add APC module or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. The simplest way to install APC module is to use PECL as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, on the server I have the packaged PHP version installed, next to the compiled PHP version. So, if I use PECL to install APC, how to use PECL to use the compiled PHP version ?

Comment: Which Linux distro is installed on your server? If it's Ubuntu/Debian, you'll have to compile `php5-dev` package which provides the files from the PHP5 source needed for compiling additional modules.